# Drag and Drop in Chrome

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, draggable

I am trying to learn about drag and drop. I am working with the following example from w3school:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop

I have copied the code exactly, and opened my own page to test it and work with it.  My copied example works in firefox, but not Chrome or IE.  Oddly, when I work with the example on the w3 page itself, it works on all three browsers.

Any idea why my copied example doesn't work in IE or Chrome?

Comment: is it coming from a server or is it directly off your filesytem

Comment: I have it set up in django, using a local server.

Comment: Just tested it by loading a .html file, same problem, works in firefox, but not chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you didn't save the image along with the html file, and when chrome went looking for it, it couldn't find it.

Once I had the html and image file in the same directory, it worked fine on chrome.

To save it, right click the image and click Save Image As...

Comment: Well, it worked for me. Mac Os x 10.7, double-clicked off the desktop. And i didn't have to change the alt or anything.

Comment: Im using windows7, maybe thats the problem?  Its weird that it works on the w3 page (iframe) in Chrome, but not on my own page with the same html.

Comment: I don't think so. Cus Chrome is cross-browser, and so is webkit/blink. Did you save the image in the same folder as the html?

Comment: No way.  I cant believe it.  You are right.  For some reason, changing the src link to alt = "img2" makes it fail in Chrome!  Why?